# Nginx Proxy Pass does... nothing?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Using Ubuntu Server 20.04, nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu).

For what it is worth I am trying to set up Jellyfin with remote access. I'm also using a dynamic domain name. I have a nextcloud service completely up and running using a similar ish set up. I also want the server to be accessible remotely.

When I access my domain name it simply takes me to the NGINX welcome page. I have removed it from site-enabled, and I have disabled the default.conf listen tags (and renamed the file default.conf.bak)

In essence what is supposed to happen is that when I type in the domain name it is supposed to automatically redirect to the correct port. It doesn't.

I can access the server using the ip address and jellyfin's port. But using the domain name or the ip address will simply get me the welcome screen. I am using the domain name primarily as I have other services that also use port 80.

I can access the Jellyfin site at it's local ip without the port.

I've tried a number of tips from elsewhere including editing the hosts file to ensure the domain name is linked to 127.0.0.1 but I'm running at a bit of a loss.

There is nothing in the access or error logs.

I've also checked the nginx.conf for any server blocks, there are none. Here's the file I'm using... (it's practically a copy paste from the the Jellyfin site).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name (scrambled).ydns.eu;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverseaccess.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverseerror.log;

    # use a variable to store the upstream proxy
    # in this example we are using a hostname which is resolved via DNS
    # (if you aren't using DNS remove the resolver line and change the variable to point to an IP address e.g `set $>


    #Security / XSS Mitigation Headers
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    # Content Security Policy
    # See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP
    # Enforces https content and restricts JS/CSS to origin
    # External Javascript (such as cast_sender.js for Chromecast) must be whitelisted.
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-sr>

    location / {
        # Proxy main Jellyfin traffic
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8096;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;

        # Disable buffering when the nginx proxy gets very resource heavy upon streaming
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    # location block for /web - This is purely for aesthetics so /web/#!/ works instead of having to go to /web/inde>
#    location ~ ^/web/$ {
#        # Proxy main Jellyfin traffic
#        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8096/web/index.html/;
#        proxy_set_header Host $host;
#        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
#    }

    location /socket {
       # Proxy Jellyfin Websockets traffic
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8096/socket/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Comment: is `/socket` endpoint working as expected?

Comment: As in does the proxy take me to port 8096? Nope.

Comment: Is nginx running? What's the output for `sudo nginx -s reload`

Answer (score 0):

Okay key thing here is that there are two machines involved. So the forwarding wasn't working as expected. I believe that it needs the redirect rather than a simple pass and the listening on port 80 wasn't going to happen. The router had no idea where it was supposed to send the information.

One key thing with Jellyfin installed it doesn't seem like you need a conf file on the host machine as it is currently supposed to be listening on 8080 but Jellyfin listens on 8096.

If someone want's to come along and give their expert opinion to fill in the blanks would be much appreciated. Thanks all for your help.

At any rate the following is now my config file for reverse proxy...

```
# Reverse proxy on forwarding machine.                                               
server {
        server_name domainname.eu;

        # Not sure if this is required, it's purpose was to see where /
        # the nginx page was being served from it wasn't the client as thought.
        root /usr/share/nginx/test; 

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8096$request_uri;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.2:8096$request_uri http://domainname.eu;
        }

    # The certbot action has to be done on the forwarding machine not \
    # the hosting machine. Any attempt to run it on the host fails. \
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.eu/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.eu/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot


    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.eu/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = domainname.eu) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name domainname.eu;
        root /usr/share/nginx/test;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8096$request_uri;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.2:8096$request_uri http://domainname.eu;
        }
}
```

Here's hoping it'll help someone in the future.